# bash/ssh test for public key authentication

Tags: bash, ssh, public-key-encryption

Is there a way to programmatically test whether ssh can authenticate using a public key? I would like to do something like this (preferably in bash, but am open to a python solution):

```
ssh-test-thingy user@host || echo "could not authenticate using publickey"
```

where `ssh-test-thingy`returns a non-zero exit status if no public key matches on the remote host.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd pass the option `-o BatchMode=yes` to ssh and see if that works.  It will disable prompting for a password, which I think is equivalent in practice to your desire to find out if authentication via keys is possible.  `ssh-test-thingy` could be written as a bash script like so:

```
exec ssh -o BatchMode=yes "$@" true
```

This will simply pass the user@host (and any other arguments) along, and try to run `true` on the remote host, which if it works will immediately return a status code of success (0).

Comment: I had to put "true" at the end of the command to get it to work, example:

  ssh -o BatchMode=yes "$@" true

Comment: Adding `-q` makes it quiet.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `exec`?

Comment: @pihentagy: `exec` replaces the current shell process with the ssh process.  This is OK because the shell is not needed any more after ssh is launched; the return value of the program should be the return value of ssh.  You could return what ssh returns without the exec, but why bother spawning one more process you don't need?

Comment: I blindly copy-pasted the solution to a function of a script, and it did not work with exec.

Comment: If you're going to put it in a function, you would need to remove the "exec" part, yes.  I wrote it that way for it to be an entire script by itself, not a function.

Comment: This assumes the "true" will get executed. First problem that comes to mind is if the account is forcing a password reset.