# Why does ssh abort my bash script?

Tags: bash, ssh, while-loop, return-code

I'm automating auth key uploads to several ssh hosts and I want to avoid adding the key to authorized_keys every time the script is executed, so I check if ssh can connect with key authentication before uploading the key.

Problem is that the script stops its loop on the first server the user already has a key in.

The script tries out key authentication based on advice from [bash/ssh test for public key authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768130/bash-ssh-test-for-public-key-authentication/5768198#5768198)

```
while read SERVER; do
    CONN="$USER@$SERVER"
    echo "$CONN: "
    ssh -q -o "BatchMode yes" $CONN 'true'
    RC=$?

    if [[ $RC -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo "key auth did not succeed, trying to uploading key:"
        ../ssh-uploadkeys/ssh-uploadkeys $CONN
    else
        echo "key auth ok, no need to upload key"
    fi
done < servers.txt
```

This outputs:

```
myusername@the.host.com: 
key auth ok, no need to upload key
```

The servers.txt:

```
the.host.com
another.host.com
the.ghost.com
```

The ssh-uploadkeys script that my script uses is written by Tero Karvinen: http://terokarvinen.com/ssh-uploadkeys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-n` option to `ssh` to prevent it reading from stdin. What is happening is that `ssh` is consuming your `servers.txt` file, so the while loop terminates after the first line because there is nothing left for it to read.