# bash: check if I can ssh (with keys) to a list of hosts

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to check if I can **ssh** to a **list of hosts** by only using **keys**.

[**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768130/bash-ssh-test-for-public-key-authentication) suggests doing the following:

```
exec ssh -o BatchMode=yes "user@host" true
```

... which should connect to the host, run `true` and return its exit status.

On my Ubuntu machine it doesn't work. Something in the above command forces the terminal to close.  What did I do wrong?

(Also, since I am required to use the `-l` option to pass my username, the regular command would be: `ssh -l user host`.  Will `exec` interpret this as something else?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec` causes the current shell to be replaced by `ssh`. When `ssh` exits, your terminal does as well. Just use

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes "user@host" true
```

to return to your shell after `ssh` completes.